# Error:(47,52) java: cannot access com.mongodb.ConnectionString - Trying to connecting MongoDB to a Java Maven project

Tags: java, database, mongodb, maven, connection-string

I have a JavaFX Maven project that I'm trying to connect to MongoDB. I'm following along a video from MDB where they do exactly this, so far I created the DB, added the dependency in the maven pom, and set up the ConnectionString code, but I'm getting the error:

```
Error:(47,52) java: cannot access com.mongodb.ConnectionString
```

Here is my pom dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

My module-info file:

```
module org.example {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires org.mongodb.driver.sync.client;

    opens org.example to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.example;
}
```

And the ConnectionString code I copied from the video (copied the connectionstring from my DB):

```
    String connectionString = "mongodb+srv://admin:javaapp@orderscluster.wcn38.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);) {
        MongoIterable<String> strings = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames();
        MongoCursor<String> cursor = strings.cursor();

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    }
```

And here is the default connection string format:

```
mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@orderscluster.wcn38.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I can't find a hard answer on what to put in for `<dbname>?` but I tried every conceivable name from my database, as well as removing it altogether, and I still get the same error. So far all the code I showed is the only changes I've made to the project. Any ideas on what's going on? Thank you!